# MySQL Delete Record only from Single Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables related with each other and I want to delete record only from one table. The table structure is below

```
Table : Users
userunique, active, unSubscribed

Table : userBilling
userunique, billCreatedDate,billstatus
```

I want to delete those bills of users who are no longer active with the conditions as follow.

```
billcreateddate < 2011-12-30 
billstatus=2 //pending

active='0'
unSubscribed<'2011-12-30'
```

I have written a query but it is not what I expected. I want to delete record only from userBilling Table and not Users Table

```
select * from userBilling ubill, Users user
WHERE ubilll.userUnique=user.userUnique 
AND ubill.billCreatedDate<'2011-12-30'
AND ubill.billstatus = '2'  
AND ((user.active = '0') AND (user.unsubscribed>'2011-01-01') 
AND user.unSubscribed<'2011-12-30'))
```

But I guess the above query includes result from both the tables. Please suggest!

Thanks,

Comment: The above query `DELETE`s nothing, it only `SELECT`s.

Comment: Do you have a `billingid` field being returned in this query? Does this query give you the records you want to delete?

Comment: Assuming that your query's conditions are fine (and that you are using `select` just for searching the values before calling `delete`), have you checked if you have some foreing keys contraints  in your tables?

Comment: @ypercube   this is select statement.. which I want to see if I am deleting correct records or not!! this is very important as to see if any important info will be deleted or not!!!

Comment: @jamison yeah there is a field named "billingid" which is unique. But if I delete  using above query.. won't it include the data from Users Table?? won't it delete the record from Users Table?

Comment: @Cynical..  no there aren't any foreign keys constraint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE  a
FROM    userBilling a
        INNER JOIN users b
            ON a.auserUnique = b.userUnique
WHERE   billcreateddate < 2011-12-30 OR
        billstatus = 2 OR
        active = 0 OR
        unSubscribed < '2011-12-30'
```

*if you want all condition to be **true***, change `OR` to `AND`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.  You should always make your joins explicit.  That way you won't be surprised.

```
DELETE ubill
FROM userBilling ubill
  JOIN Users u
  ON (ubill.userUnique=u.userUnique)
WHERE ubill.billCreatedDate<'2011-12-30'
  AND ubill.billstatus = '2'  
  AND ((u.active = '0') AND (u.unsubscribed>'2011-01-01') 
  AND u.unSubscribed<'2011-12-30'))
```

Comment: It gives me error saying "Column 'ubill' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: @MadanMadan: try `DELETE ubill.* ...`. It shouldn't make any difference, but then again, so far as I can see, that error shouldn't be occurring.

Comment: This query doesn't work with SELECT  isn't it? it only works with DELETE  also can I use limit  in this query?

Answer (score 0):

try do this

```
     DELETE ubill
      FROM userBilling ubill
     INNER JOIN Users
     ON  ubill.userUnique=user.userUnique
      WHERE  
        ubill.billCreatedDate<'2011-12-30'
        AND ubill.billstatus = '2'  
        AND user.active = '0' 
        AND user.unsubscribed>'2011-01-01' 
        AND user.unSubscribed<'2011-12-30'
```